# Dynamically adding inner HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to read a XML file using jQuery and trying to add named tags as options for select  dropdown in my HTML page.

For some weird reason I am not able to add that HTML into my select element.

Following is my Javascript:

```
 $.get("DeliveryCenter.xml", {}, function (xml) {
          myHTMLOutput = '';

          $('DC', xml).each(function (i) {
              DCName = $(this).find("name").text();
              DCvalue = $(this).find("value").text();
              mydata = BuildHTML(DCName, DCvalue);
              myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;
          });
          //myHTMLOutput += '</select>';
          alert(myHTMLOutput);
          $("#chkDCXML").html(myHTMLOutput);
          alert($('#chkDCXML').html());
      });
```

Here BuildHTML successfully returns me option html tags which is alerted in  `alert(myHTMLOutput);`

However I get undefined for 
`alert($('#chkDCXML').html());`

Any help on what i am doing wrong or missing here?

EDIT:

The Build HTML function:

```
function BuildHTML(DCName, DCValue) {

          output = '';
          output += '<option value="' + DCValue + '">' + DCName + '</option>';
          return output;
      }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: Can you post your "BuildHTML"'s source code ?

Comment: What type of element is `#chkDCXML`? If it's a `<select>`, try with `$('#chkDCXML').append(myHTMLOutput);`

Comment: Yes chkDCXML is Select type. But .append is not helping either. Still undefined returned.

Comment: Well, `append()` should have [**worked**](http://jsfiddle.net/5tkbd/). If it isn't, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: use $("#chkDCXML").html($.parseHTML(myHTMLOutput)); or  $("#chkDCXML").append($.parseHTML(myHTMLOutput));

Comment: Well, the issues is with the element itself. I am not able to reference it. Will check and post. 
Thanks for now Asprin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asprin pointed out in comments, answer is indeed .append()

jsfiddle.net/5tkbd/

Thanks all.

P.S. 
As it turned out that I was dynamically building Select and applying bootstrap's multiselect on it in one go. This was changing ID of my element. Its fixed now.